# Preventing python to escape regexp pattern while inserting into list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to create a list of regexp pattern which I can use for patter matching like below one

```
REGEXES = [
'port .\d+',
'te\d+-\d+ \d+ [@]?\d+',
'te\d+.-\d+'
]
```

Now while I am checking the o/p of it, its shows

```
['port .\\d+', 'te\\d+-\\d+ \\d+ [@]?\\d+', 'te\\d+.-\\d+']
```

And using below code

```
msg = "Aborting Test: checkDutPort: Invalid dutBladeAndPort: te3932-213 0 @4, not found in global ::dutPortMap"
combined = "(" + ")|(".join(REGEXES) + ")"
re.match(combined, msg)
```

it not able to match the pattern.
I check but for raw input also python escaped the "\".

How can I prevent this.

Comment: Do you want to use `re.match` or `re.search` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

None of your patterns can be found at the beginning of `msg`, so it returns `None`.

If instead you use `re.search`, it will find the part of the string I assume you're looking for:

```
>>> re.search(combined, msg)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(54, 69), match='te3932-213 0 @4'>
```